# Is there a "Go to Coordinates" command?

Tags: x3-terran-conflict

I'm just starting out, and having trouble navigating space in 3 dimensions. Even when I know what coordinates I want, I have a difficult time getting there. Is there any way to target a specific X,Y,Z coordinate so I can aim for it manually or autopilot to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, in sector map. Change axis and navigate the blinking cursor with the numpad arrows, then click on the cursor.

[image: how to...]

[image: ...do it]

There are mods/scripts that make it even easier to navigate, I don't have the links to them though.

Comment: Having to use the numpad threw me off. I had been using the regular arrow keys, which only let you select objects already on your map.